# text to HTML with ASP.net mvc4

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

So i am trying to make an html page generator. the idea is that you have a textarea where you put html code. and have buttons on the side to load in elements like a table or title for example. and i want to be able to load those in multiple times in a single page.
[here](http://www.naturalcrit.com/homebrew/) is an example of something i would like to make except i want it a bit more simplistic.

does anyone have any suggestions on how that could be done or what tools could be used to accomplish something like this in ASP.net mvc4?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example uses advanced markdown. Not sure if you'd want this as well. If you only need to convert textarea input to html, you can just post your form to your controller action that handles `HttpPost`, and then append the raw html content to your (View)Model. In your view use `@Html.Raw(Model.HtmlContent)` and voila!

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult MyPostAction(string htmlContent)
     {
          return View(htmlContent);
     }
}
```